# multiple marker on same address location show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create an app to show multiple marker with product job and services. Now if address is same in google map only one marker come though lot of product may same place. So I want how many time call address that much marker come though it same location.

```
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+json[i].DisType+'&sensor=false',

$.getJSON(url, null, function (data)
{
    var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i)
    {
        return function() 
        {
            infowindow.setContent(r);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
});
```

Comment: 213 Al Sinyar Street - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
product.html:1614 293 Al Satwa Rd - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
product.html:1614 Dubai Silicon Oasis - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
product.html:1614 Tecom - Al Barsha - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
product.html:1614 Pearl Jumeirah - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
product.html:1614 Gerbera Court - Green Community Village - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
product.html:1614 FERTIL - Ruwais - United Arab Emirates

Comment: that address i passed into address.where dubai silicon oasis 3 times

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the response `var p = data.results[0].geometry.location` you are only creating a marker of the first item in the response

```
var item;
for(item in data.results){
    var p = item.geometry.location
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i)
    {
        return function() 
        {
            infowindow.setContent(r);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```